# send arbitrary number of arguments to event emitter listener

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I'm trying to create a function that takes arguments, turn that into an array then  select the first element from the array as the event and then passes the rest of the elements as the parameters.

Example:

```
// _ is the underscore module
// emitter = new events.EventEmitter()
function sendToEmitter = function(){
    var args  = _.toArray(arguments),
        event = args[0],
        rest  = args.slice(1);
    emitter.emit(event, rest)
```

I'm not sure how to pass `rest` as separate arguments to the listener function.

In python I could simply just turn it into a tuple and pack it with `*`. I'm not sure if JavaScript has something similar. Is there any way to achieve this? I believe .apply( maybe .call? ) would work but I'm not sure how to apply the arguments to a listener.

Comment: something like `emitter.emit.apply(emitter, [event, args])` would probably work, but it's not really clear how you want to add the arguments, `apply` accepts an array of arguments, so you could just pass it, the reason for taking the `event` argument out is not clear to me ?

Comment: @adeneo I wanted to separate them to add some default parameters so I wouldn't have to type them all each time, but I was over thinking the problem too much and I didn't realize I could use `.apply` right on the emit function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, what you want to do is to pass an array as multiple parameters to a function.

You can use [`.apply(thisArg, [argsArray])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

```
var args  = _.toArray(arguments),
emitter.emit.apply(emitter, args);
```

Comment: Wow, okay. Thank you I had a stupid moment and was over thinking this way too much. I will accept this answer as soon as the time allows it.

Comment: You should avoid passing `arguments` to another function if you care about the function that code is in. Passing `arguments` is one way to cause "leaking" and (at least in v8's case) the javascript engine will deoptimize that function. See [this](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers#32-leaking-arguments) for more information, examples, and solutions.

Comment: @mscdex: the article you linked to says *"Never use `arguments` directly without `.length` or `[i]` (STRICTLY `x.apply(y, arguments)` is ok, nothing else is, e.g. `.slice`. `Function#apply` is special)"*

Comment: @FelixKling In the section I linked to it specifically says, "the `arguments` object must not be passed or leaked anywhere." Also, as I mentioned, `_.toArray()` calls `[].slice()` on the value passed in. So there are two "strikes" there if you care about v8 performance (for that particular piece of code).

Comment: @mscdex: Right, but it would be fine to pass it directly to `.apply`.

Comment: @FelixKling That is correct, but that's not what is being done in this case.